# cp recursively into a directory that symlinks to dirs of same name as in source

Tags: cp

```
cp -r src/* dest/
```

If `src/` & `dest/` both contain a directory `foo`, the contents of `src/foo/` are copied into `dest/foo/`, which is desired.

If `dest/` instead contains a symlink `foo -> /sym/foo` to a directory elsewhere, the command errors:

> cp: cannot overwrite non-directory 'dest/foo' with directory 'src/foo'

Is it possible to copy following the *target* symlink, with GNU `cp`? As far as I can tell it only has an option (`-L`/`--dereference`) for following *source* symlinks.

Comment: I assume that the target of `foo` really is a directory?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question to be clearer about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this behaviour with `rsync`'s `--keep-dirlinks` option:

From `man rsync (1)`:

> `-K, --keep-dirlinks`
>
> This option causes the receiving side to treat a symlink to a directory as though it were a real directory, but only if it
>   matches a real directory from the sender. Without this option, the receiver’s symlink would be deleted and replaced with a
>   real directory.
>
> For example, suppose you transfer a directory "foo" that contains a file "file", but "foo" is a symlink to directory "bar" on
>   the receiver. Without `--keep-dirlinks`, the receiver deletes symlink "foo", recreates it as a directory, and receives the file
>   into the new directory. With `--keep-dirlinks`, the receiver keeps the symlink and "file" ends up in "bar".

Example:

```
rsync -av --keep-dirlinks src/ dest
```

Comment: Thanks, I anticipated `rsync` would probably do it; I was hoping to solve it neatly (more so than present for loop) without installing it. (So I won't accept this answer because I did say "with GNU cp", but thanks, and I'm sure it will be helpful to others.)